# Finding IP Address of application on CloudBees

Tags: ip-address, cloudbees

I've followed the advice here:

http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/Main/Finding+out+app+port+and+hostname

```
public String getIp() throws UnknownHostException {
    String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
    String urlToRead = "http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-hostname";
    String iVeALsoTriedThis = "http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/" + hostName;
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    BufferedReader rd;
    String line;
    String result = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(urlToRead);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return hostName + " ------ " + result;
}
```

And when using on the homepage a simple tag to obtain the details:

```
IP: <s:property value="ip"/>
```

The result I get is this:

IP: ip-10-34-128-137.eu-west-1.compute.internal ------ ec2-46-51-131-172.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

This was not what I was expecting - even when I tried to access 10.34.128.137 I just get a timeout error. Also pinging 46.51.131.172 gets timed out and trying to access ec2-46-51-131-172.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com also brings timout.

I know most of you would consider this trivial, but there's no easy way on cloudbees to identify the IP of your app from the console, and then following their (usually clear advice) I get completely lost.

Please, what should I be doing here?

Many thanks,

Ken

Comment: And the reason I wish to know this info is so that I can point my domain name to the app.  I've tried adding an CNAME for the domain name to point to the cloudbees app address but this is not working either (after having waited 48 hours :o/  )

Answer (score 0):

URL to call to retrieve public hostname is

```
http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/public-hostname
```

don't append your own host name or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You generally do not want the IP address of the server your application is running on - it is behind a router which does all kinds of wonderful stuff that PaaSs do (clustering, load-balancing, fail-over, encryption, etc)

If you want to assign a CNAME for `www.example.com` (or an A record for a domain apex - e.g. `example.com`) then you should assign it to the A record shown in the RUN console.

If your app is fred and your account is example:

```
$ host fred.example.cloudbees.net
fred.example.cloudbees.net has address 75.101.143.131
```

Then assign

- your `CNAME` against `fred.example.cloudbees.net`; or
- your `A` record against `75.101.143.131`

See this document for more information that is **quite important** as part of your configuration:
https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Custom+Application+Domains